# Need help in recording mutual funds on tax returns

Tags: capital-gains-tax

If I record the proceeds and costs of all short term and long term mutual fund transactions, why are there additional capital gain distributions?  It seems like double taxation.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you looking at?

Comment: Specifically, does this circumstance differ from this one: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/capital-gains-and-capital-gain-distributions-for-a-mutual-fund?rq=1